# return the matching values from the end of one list and the start of another python

Tags: python

I am trying to return the matching values from the end of one list and the start of another. Both lists are sorted. Here are examples to explain it better:

`[7,8,9]` and `[8,9,10,11,12]` returns `[8,9]` since the first list ends in 8,9 and the second list starts with 8,9.

`[1,2,3,4,4]` and `[3,4,4,5,6]` returns `[3,4,4]` since the first list ends in 3,4,4 and the second list starts with 3,4,4.

Can someone suggest a possible method for this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using list operations to retrieve the last value of the first list and compare to the first value of the last list then if it is the same then compare the first two value of each, but that doesnt account for the second list beginning with a number lower than the value at the end of the first list

Comment: Hint: you can use negative indices to index from the end of the list. You are trying to find the largest `i` for which `l1[-i:] == l2[:i]`.

Comment: I will try that thanks

Comment: (Caveat: slices are always defined even when the indices are out of range, so make sure you don't go into an infinite loop of seeing that empty lists are equal to each other.)

Answer (score 1):

you could use next() to find the first suffix of the first list that matches the beginning of the second list:

```
A = [7,8,9]
B = [8,9,10,11,12]

C = next( A[i:] for i in range(len(A)+1) if A[i:] == B[:len(A)-i] )

# [8, 9]
```

Comment: I think you can remove the +1 in the range(len(A)+1)

Comment: next() will crash if it doesn't find at least one match, so the +1  makes sure to check an empty sublist as the last attempt. (so there will alsways be something returned by next)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
l2 = [3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    print(l1[i:], l2[:len(l1)-i])    # optional
    if l1[i:] == l2[:len(l1)-i]: break

print(l1[i:])
```

Comment: Great idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start by finding the first element of `b` matching the last of `a`, then slide until the other way around is True. If you don't find the element or go beyond the max, there is no match.

```
def match(a, b):
    try:
        i = b.index(a[-1])+1
        while a[-i] != b[0]:
            i+=1
        return b[:i]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        return []

match([7,8,8,9,9], [8,9,9,10,11,12])
# [8, 9, 9]

match([1,2,6], [4,5,6])
# []
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reverse list1 and then compare the first element of list1 and list2. If they match then you save that value in a new list.

```py
[x for x,y in zip(list2,reversed(list1) if x==y]
```

Comment: You aren't trying to compare the last element of one list to the first element of another; you are trying to compare *suffixes* of the first list to *prefixes* of the second.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake.